# Constant Taylor Polynomials imply $f(x)=const.$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

How do I best formally verify or disprove the following statement:

> If for an arbitrarily often differentiable function $f(x)$, the Taylor Polynomials are constant
>
> $$T_n(x)=const. \forall n\in \mathbb{N}_0$$
>
> then
>
> $$f(x)=const. \text{on } \mathbb{R}$$

How can an arbitrarily often differentiable function be constant? I am stuck on this question.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's false. Counter-example:

Consider the function $f$ defined by
$$\begin{cases}f(x)=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac 1{x^2}}&\text{if }x\ne0,\\f(0)=0.\end{cases}$$

One checks that $f$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ on $\mathbf R$ and that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$, so is Taylor series (and its Taylor polynomials) is $0$. Yet $f(x)\ne 0$ if $x\ne 0$.